# geom_freqpoly not plotting when I run this chunk of code with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I don't know why geom_freqpoly is not graphing. When I run the chunk I only see the histogram but not the line graph.

```
library(ggplot2)
lambda1 = 1/2
sequence = seq(1, 10000, by=1)
    

df1 = tibble(x=seq(1, 10000, by=1), expo1 = lambda1*exp(-(lambda1)*x))

lambda2 = 1/5

df2 = tibble(x=seq(1, 10000, by=1), expo2 = lambda2*exp(-(lambda2)*x))


ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=expo2, y=..density..), binwidth=.5, colour="blue", fill="white") +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=expo1, y=..density..), binwidth=.5, colour="red", fill="white") +
  geom_freqpoly(data=df2, aes(x=expo2, y=..density..), binwidth=.5, colour="blue") + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(expo2)), color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666") +
  geom_freqpoly(data=df1, aes(x=expo1, y=..density..), binwidth=.5, colour="red") + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(expo1)), color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666") +
  xlim(0,10) +
  ylim(0,0.5)+
  ggtitle("Distribution of averages of random exponential distribution with their means", "theta = 2 in red and theta = 5 in ")+
  xlab("Averages of the distribution")+
  ylab("Density")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `data` object in many of your geom lines. Each geom needs data. What are you trying to do? Plot two dataframes on one plot? Your scales are all over the place. Try this.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

x <- seq(0, 10, by = 0.1)

lambda1 <- 1 / 2
df1 <- tibble(x = x, expo1 = lambda1 * exp(-(lambda1) * x))

lambda2 <- 1 / 5
df2 <- tibble(x = x, expo2 = lambda2 * exp(-(lambda2) * x))

ggplot() +
  ggtitle("Distribution of averages of random exponential distribution with their means", "theta = 2 in red and theta = 5 in blue") +
  xlab("Averages of the distribution") +
  ylab("Density") +
  geom_histogram(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = expo2), stat = "identity", colour = "blue", fill = "white") +
  geom_freqpoly(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = expo2), stat = "identity", colour = "blue") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = lambda2, color = "blue", linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = expo2), stat = "identity", alpha = .2, fill = "#FF6666") +
  geom_histogram(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = expo1), stat = "identity", colour = "red", fill = "white") +
  geom_freqpoly(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = expo1), stat = "identity", colour = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = lambda1, color = "red", linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = expo1), stat = "identity", alpha = .2, fill = "#FF6666")
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad

#> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to plot the two dataframes in one plot. Even after specifying the data object, the line graph is still not plotting.

Comment: geom_density also needs a aesthetic. I'm fiddling with it now.

Comment: The scale needs to be x = 0 to 10 and it seems to graph fine when df1 = tibble(x=seq(1, 10000, by=1), expo1 = rexp(10000, lambda1)) and df2 = tibble(x=seq(1, 10000, by=1), expo2 = rexp(10000, lambda2)). I'm trying to replicate that with the actual PDF for exponential distribution with lambda*exp(-(lambda)*x).

Comment: df1 and df2 are the already density functions. It doesn't really make sense to make histograms or freqpoly or density of them. You already have the density in expo1 expo2.

Comment: Is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah this makes perfect sense. What does stat="identity" by the way?

Comment: these geoms usually use stat = "bin" by default to bin the data and plot a statistical summary (e.g. histogram, density). Setting stat = "identity" tells them just to use the y values you have supplied.

Comment: I think geom_histogram, geom_freqpoly and geom_density are all trying to much the same thing, it's redundant to have all of them.